# How to select custom listview item with edittext?

Tags: android, listview, textview, android-edittext, listitem

I've made multiple custom listview items with only textviews and when I click them I can select them. But now i've made a list item that has 3 edittexts in it and it won't work. Even tried to put a textview next to it, but that doesn't help eather.

**Does anyone know how to?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what doesn't work? you can't press your edittext??

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Can you post your xml or snapshot of your requirement??

Comment: I want to be able to select a listitem and delete it. But somehow the edittexts are interfering! In the past I made listitems with just textviews and i was able to select the item and i build it the same way!

Answer (score 0):

You just need your list item (whatever type it is - `XYZLayout` or any other view) to implement the `Checkable` interface. "Checkable" practically means selectable in the Android terms.

You can just copy this class into your project. Note that it is `RelativeLayout` but you could make it to work with other layouts type too:

[CheckableRelativeLayout.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.0.1_r1/com/android/music/CheckableRelativeLayout.java)

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late for party but I'm posting for someone who might face same issue. To make your list item selctable, you need to make your EditText not focusable by `setFocusable(false)` in `getView()`.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);
  EditText et1 = (EditText) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.view1);
  EditText et2 = (EditText) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.view2);

  // You need to make EditText not editable to prevent them to intercept focus from list view.
  et1.setFocusable(false);
  et2.setFocusable(false);

  CustomListItem item = listViewItemList.get(position);
  et1.setText(item.view1Value);
  et2.setText(item.view2Value);

  return listItemView;
}
```